# Add more keys for 5x7 matrix keypad driver

Tags: drivers, keypad

I am trying to integrate 5x7 matrix keypad on qualcomm based chipset. I am checking the working of keypad using "evtest" command and I can see response of the keys. The command "evtest" shows that I have only 35 keycode events supported to get response from the matrix keypad (image attached).

Now I want to add more keys as my keypad has multiplexed keys i.e. one key has two operations. How can I increase the number keycode supported events as evtest shows? Do I need to do anything in driver level?

[image: evtest screenshot]

I have synced keycodes in driver level for the keys as per my keypad. But I am not able to get any key events beyond keycode 35 as. Evtest also shows same thing. Please help me how to increase keycode event support.
Thanks...

Comment: What do you press to trigger the alternative function for a key (as opposed to the main function)? Has it anything to do with `KEY_LEFTCTRL`?

Comment: Its shift key on my keypad.

Comment: Does the sole shift key generate any event? If so, what is it?

Comment: As of now I am not generating any keyevent on shift key, just toggling a flag in driver to check if shift is held or not. If it is held I am raising key event with keycode for alternative function.

Comment: As you can see above some alphabets are not present like KEY_J, KEY_K, KEY_L, KEY_M etc. as they are beyond keycode 35. Please let me know how to increase keycode event support.